# EntityFramework code first Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

i when i try to save my entitie buzzmate i have this exception :

```
     An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

this is the code that generate this exception :

```
        var p = Session["mayaProfile"] as MayaProfile;
        BuzzMate buzzmate = new BuzzMate();
        buzzmate.MayaProfile = p;
        SocialBuzzCompaign socialcampaign = _buzzService.GetSocialBuzzCompaign(model.socialBuzzCompaignId);
        //Ajouter le BuzzMate
        buzzmate.SocialBuzzCompaign = socialcampaign;
        buzzmate.JoiningStatus = JoiningStatus.Approved;
        buzzmate.SelectionType = BuzzMateSelectionType.InvitedByBuzzLeader;                     
        //try
        //
        _buzzService.AddBuzzMate(buzzmate);
```

and this is method AddBuzzMate :

```
    public void AddBuzzMate(BuzzMate buzzMate)
    {
        _buzzMateRepository.Insert(buzzMate);
        _buzzMateRepository.Save();
    }
```

when  i try to save buzzmate i have exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most probably `p`. Don't use entities stored in session for persistence or you will not avoid this error. Try to create clone of `p` and assign it to `buzzmate` and if you use same EF context for loading `socialcampaign` and persisting `buzzmate` it should work.

Comment: yes Mr Ladislav , in fact i use the pattern repository and unit of work , so i work with the same context for loading my entities, i will try your suggestion !!!

Comment: I try your suggestion to clone p: MayaProfile maya = (MayaProfile)p.Clone(); but the problem persist , it's can be caused by ? BuzzMate buzzmate = new BuzzMate();

Comment: Are there any related entities inside MayaProfile?

Comment: Yes there is entity related at MayaProfile , but i resolve this problem now ;) , i added proprety in buzzmate (MayaProfileId) and i do this "buzzmate.MayaProfileId = p.MayaProfileId;" rather than "buzzmate.MayaProfile = p;" , thanks Mr ladislav for your help ;)